# Move files 5 levels deep into parent and delete child folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
Root (level0)
    ABC (level1)
        Amazon (level2)
            Spring (level3)
                April (level4)
                    Filename.jpg (level5)
                    Filename02.jpg
                    Filename03.jpg
    DEF (level1)
        Denmark (level2)
            Fall (level3)
                October (level4)
                    Filename01.jpg (level5)
                    Filename02.jpg
                    Filename03.jpg
```

Basically, I have my root folder and in that folder I have categorized my files as such ex. ABC > Amazon > Spring > Date > Filename01.jpg and so forth.

I am trying to figure out a way to move any file types (not all are .jpg) out of the LEVEL4 folder and into the parent (i.e LEVEL3 folder) and then delete the LEVEL4 folder. So it would look like this

```
Root (level0)
    ABC (level1)
        Amazon (level2)
            Spring (level3)
                Filename.jpg (level4)
                Filename02.jpg
                Filename03.jpg
    DEF (level1)
        Denmark (level2)
            Fall (level3)
                Filename01.jpg (level4)
                Filename02.jpg
                Filename03.jpg
```

I have searched and found some solutions to similar problems but none of them are quite like this. I tried modifying to get the results I wanted but nothing has worked. I would like to make a batch file that I can place inside the root folder and run it.
I found this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1146686/move-all-files-within-subfolders-to-parent-folder) and tried modifying the parent to go 4 levels down.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET parent="C:\Users\ht-100\Documents\photos\*\*\*\*"
CD /d %parent% 
FOR /r %parent% %%d IN (*.*) DO MOVE "%%d" %parent% 
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /a:d /s /b ^| SORT /r') DO RD "%%d"
ECHO Done. Press any key to terminate script.
PAUSE >NUL
```

Comment: You can't use wildcards like this, they only work when used in the last element of a path...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have got a specific directory hierarchy depth I would rather go for nested [`for /D` loops](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) instead of a `for /R` loop:

```cmd
@echo off
for /D %%A in ("%UserProfile%\Documents\photos\*") do (
    for /D %%B in ("%%~A\*") do (
        for /D %%C in ("%%~B\*") do (
            for /D %%D in ("%%~C\*") do (
                move "%%~D\*.*" "%%~C"
            )
            rd "%%~D"
        )
    )
)
```